# style the thumb of range input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, input

I want to change the background color of the thumb with jquery. 
I tried the following:

```
<input id="size" type="range" name="size" min="2" max="10" step="0.01" value="5">

$('#color').click(function(){
    var col = ($(this)[0].checked) ? '#000' : '#FFF';
    $('input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb').css('background-color', col);
});
```

But this gives me an

> syntax error, unrecognized expression

How do i do this with Jquery?

Comment: FYI styling sliders is pretty complicated, https://css-tricks.com/styling-cross-browser-compatible-range-inputs-css/

Comment: Can you provide the slider you want to change?

Comment: I added the html slider element for you

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but it might be easier for you to use the [jQuery UI slider plugin](https://jqueryui.com/slider/)?

Comment: @MarcBellêtre yeah this would work, but i dont want to add an entire library to do one basic thing once a while :) So i am still hoping for a solution using only jquery / javascript

Comment: What are web browser's that you have tested this code with?

Comment: chrome, firefox, opera, safari

Comment: @FutureCake the last variable, `col` is undefined. This is the cause of the error. However, the style that you could not apply inline, you will not able to apply it using JavaScript. This feature is browser's UI feature like scroll bar, alert box, etc and you could not able to change it, simply, using just CSS.

Comment: col is defined let me add some more code to explain